# How to build boringSSL with MIPS arch?

Tags: android, mips64, boringssl

I am trying to build the boringSSL at the master branch for my Android project. I need to build it to support MIPS and MIPS64 as well. However, the `CMakeLists.txt` file simply does not have definition for this arch, and I got an error when generating build script.

I made some simple update to unblock the build script:

```
elseif (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR} STREQUAL "mips")
  set(ARCH "mips")
elseif (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR} STREQUAL "mips64")
  set(ARCH "mips64")
```

The build works so far. But I think Google disable MIPS support for a reason. And I want to know what risks/problems I would ran into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pay attention, ARCH is only used to add special flags for arm architecture on Android.

Just remove :

```
else()
message(FATAL_ERROR "Unknown processor:" ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR})
```

and add double quotes around ${ARCH} usages like below:

```
"${ARCH}"
```

Comment: Yes, I know I can by pass that error by modifying the build script. But I also want to know why Google did not support it. May be there's a risk?

Comment: BoringSSL is a library for internal use of Google, it is not intended to be used as general 3rdparty library. The amount of MIPS Android devices  doesn't make it worth to support it. Have you tried to find any MIPS device? I found one cheap tablet from China sometime ago but it was the only one.

Comment: I have to agree with that :)